Shortcut to return to a specific part of a webpage
I'll be very precise: I recently visited a website. In the introduction part there is a
rq1 with description of what it is. Then rq2, and rq3. Now as you go through the rest of the sections of the webpage, the authors mention the word rq(1/2/3) whenever they are talking about them. So I'm not trying to remember them and I've seen in other webpages that whenver this kind of reference happens, the author of the webpage gives you a feature. He hyperlinks the word to the section describing it in the same webpage whenver he mentions it.Since this functionality is not available in the webpage I'm currently reading, I want help doing this:
Whenever there is a mention of rq1/2/3 I want the words to be hyperlinked to the specific descriptions of them in the same webpage.
The description of the rq(1/2/3) is in the introduction section of the webpage. Now the authors mention the words rq(1/2/3) in some other section and I want them to be clickable and when clicked they should take me to their respective descriptions in the introduction section.I want this to happen to every  occurence of rq(1/2/3) in the webpage. I'm only doing it so that I could easily read the webpage and for fun. I'm not helping the authors of the webpage add this functionality to it.
I'll provide the link to the webpage, and in the introduction section you'll see:
Rq1(which is in bold and basically a question):https://arxiv.org/html/2403.17336v1#:~:text=2.1%20Definition%20and%20Principle%20of%20LLM%20Jailbreak,-Report%20issue%20for&text=In%20our%20context%2C%20we%20define,constraints%20imposed%20by%20the%20developers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#linking_to_an_element_on_the_same_page

You should use this platform as a means to help solve an issue you're having. But, a general guideline for you:
All the points of the page you want to scroll to via click of a link or button or whatever else, put it in a div. 
Then, using javascript you can tell it to run a function whenever you click your button, link etc... to scroll until the div with id "BulletPoints1" or whatever you call it is in view of the viewport.
Be sure to label each div with a UNIQUE id so it knows which section you are referring to.
Hope this helps.

You can do this using either:

named anchors eg <a name="nav_galah"/>
the id attribute eg <h2 class="pageheader__content__heading" id="top_cockatoo">level 2 heading</h2>, as mentioned by j06891 above

You can then link to them using #, either within the current page eg <a href="#nav_galah">Jump to Galah</a>, or from another page eg <a href="prize_parrots.htm#top_cockatoo">the Top Cockatoo</a>.
